# Easy way of representing multiple inputs in keras?

Tags: python, for-loop, keras

I am working on a CNN implementation in which there are multiple (72) inputs.

Each input is processed the same way, and then they are concatenated together.

Currently, I've written out each input and the process for the 72 which not only looks ugly, but takes up a lot of space (size vs. function).

Is it possible to define multiple outputs using some `for` loop structure?

I simple need to do this:

```
input = Input(shape(1,78,3))
conv_1_0 = Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,6) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" , name = "conv_1d_1_0")(input)
```

for 72 different inputs, but all the inputs have the same shape.

currently, I have

```
input0 = Input(shape(1,78,3))
input1 = Input(shape(1,78,3))
input2 = Input(shape(1,78,3))

conv_1_0 = Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,6) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" , name = "conv_1d_1_0")(input0)
conv_1_1 = Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,6) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" , name = "conv_1d_1_1")(input1)
conv_1_2 = Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,6) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" , name = "conv_1d_1_1")(input2)
```

..

Is it possible to do it in some `for` loop in `keras`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inputs_list = [Input(shape=(1,78,3)) for i in range(72)]
conv_1_list = [Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,6) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" , name = "conv_1d_1_0")(input_tensor) for input_tensor in inputs_list]
```

Does that work? :-)